# CSS transform:scale() introduces a scrollbar in Firefox, how to get rid of it?

Tags: css, firefox, zooming, css-transforms

We're using the CSS declaration `transform:scale(n)` to emulate zooming via browser settings (such as `ctrl`-`+`, `ctrl`-`-` or `ctrl`-`mousewheel`). This works as intended in Webkit browsers, but Firefox extends the page downwards beyond the visible height and displays a scroll bar.

Reduced to the minimal case, the page structure looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="middle-col">
        This is the middle column.
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #999;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    transform-origin: top left;
}
#middle-col {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
```

When zoomed out to 80%, the following settings are applied:

```
body.scale80 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
    transform: scale(.8);
    width: 125%;   /* 100/.8 */
    height: 125%;  /* 100/.8 */
}
```

How do I avoid the vertical scrollbar that appears in Firefox?

The same page displays properly in Firefox (= without scrollbars) when using `Ctrl`-`+/-`.

- Static example: http://jsfiddle.net/qf1vjauj/1/
- Dynamic example: http://jsfiddle.net/8uqk1med/3/

Note: this is a special case design. I appreciate that in general, page zooming should be left as a user choice.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you managed to solve your problem yet, but I had the same issue. Solved it by setting the parent div to overflow:hidden.